# ddrescue rescued "0 B" under current status?

Tags: ddrescue, hard-drive-failure

`ddrescue` rescued "0 B" under current status?

Here is a picture of the screen showing 0 bytes rescued and with `/dev/sda` messages on the side (are they error messages?):

[image]

There doesn't seem to be any write activity on the image drive.

Should I let `ddrescue` continue?

The failing hard drive has been making sounds since a couple days ago. The last time that I was able to access the drive on Windows Vista was over several hours ago. I was trying to copy all files to a new drive, but the drive turned off and disappeared from Windows Explorer. After restart, Computer Management says that the drive is uninitialized. SMART status is warning about failure.

The failing hard drive (750 GB) is connected to the motherboard by SATA cable. NTFS.

The image hard drive (2 TB) is a new external USB drive. NTFS. Mounted using:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdf1 /mnt/sdf1
```

Using Ubuntu-Rescue-Remix 12.04.

Here is `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`:

[image]

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

> Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
>
> Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label

Comment: What is the output of "fdisk -l" ?

Comment: Also I would suggest taking a look at dd_rescue, totally different disk recovery tool.  I have had much better luck with it.

Comment: @jmreicha, edited OP.

Comment: What is /dev/sr0?  Do we know?  I would suggest booting into a Knoppix Live CD and see if you can get read/write on the drive, then try dd_rescue.